# OpenCV camera calibration in Python without using cv2.findChessboardCorners

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I am trying to use openCV for camera calibration. I do not have a problem as long as I use the cv2.findChessBoardCorners to find my calibration targets in the image, but if I use my own function to find the points and build an array with the points, I get an error when trying to estimate the camera parameters. Here is an example that will throw the same error.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


pattern_size         = (4, 3)
pattern_points       = np.zeros( (np.prod(pattern_size), 3), np.float32 )
pattern_points[:,:2] = np.indices(pattern_size).T.reshape(-1, 2)
pattern_points      *= 20

obj_points = []
img_points = []

for fn in range(5):
    corners = np.asarray(pattern_points[:,1:], dtype=np.float32)

    img_points.append(corners.reshape(-1, 2))
    obj_points.append(pattern_points)


ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(obj_points,
                                                   img_points,
                                                   (1088, 2048),
                                                   None,
                                                   None)
```

If I instead make the corners array with the usual

```
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (4,3))
```

it works fine. The type of corners is an ndarray size (12,2) in both cases and the elements are float32.

Why do I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (imagePoints1 should contain vector of vectors of points of type Point2f) in cv::collectCalibrationData, file C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp, line 2982
```

when I try to construct the img_points array from scratch instead of using cv2.findChessboardCorners?

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] please. Trying to run your code gives (inter alia): cv2.error: /home/openstack/opencv/opencv/opencv-3.0.0/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp:2982: error: (-210) imagePoints1 should contain vector of vectors of points of type Point2f in function collectCalibrationData

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I pasted the wrong error. I will correct that right away! The problem description is correct though and the code reproduces the error, so it would be great if you could give me any pointers.

Comment: I've been having the same issue. I solved it by using a vector of vectors, as documented; for each frame,  imPts = [ [px0, py0, pz0],..., [pxn, pyn, pzn] ] and obPts = [ [qx0, qy0],..., [qxn, qyn] ],  then do:
`imPts.astype('float32')`, `obPts.astype('float32')`  when using them inside the function.
If more than one frame is used, then do that for each frame. Hope that does the trick

Comment: ok. That works. Thanks. I made the following change to the example:

    img_points.append(corners.reshape(-1, 2).astype('float32'))
    obj_points.append(pattern_points.astype('float32'))

Since I have already casted to float32 I was surprised that it made a difference.

Comment: can we consider this as solved?

Comment: @trox you are my hero! it works like a charm after hours of frustration.

Comment: @Guy; thanks, I am glad that it helped you out. I will make it an answer to this question, seems it worth of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been having the same issue. I solved it by using a vector of vectors, as documented; for each frame,
    `imPts = [ [px0, py0, pz0],..., [pxn, pyn, pzn] ]`, *and*
    `obPts = [ [qx0, qy0],..., [qxn, qyn] ]`, then do: `imPts.astype('float32')` and `obPts.astype('float32')`, when using them inside the function. If more than one frame is used, then do that for each frame. That does the trick.